# Filter vector based new label introduced by `label_replace`

Tags: grafana, prometheus, promql

In Prometheus I'm trying to merge multiple http request lines into groups using `label_replace`.

```
http_requests_total{account_id="124",handler="AAAAAController"...}
http_requests_total{account_id="125",handler="BBBBBController"...}
http_requests_total{account_id="126",handler="CCCCCController"...}
http_requests_total{account_id="123",handler="XXXXXController"...}
```

The query I wrote is :

`label_replace(http_requests_total, "class", "$1", "handler", "([a-zA-Z0-9]+)Controller.*")` .

This works correctly and adds the `class` label to vector :"AAAA","BBBB" etc. At this point I would like to remove certain classes such as empty and `BBBB`.

How can I further filter the vector using `{class~="BBBBB"}` :

`label_replace(http_requests_total, "class", "", "handler", "([a-zA-Z0-9]+)Controller.*"){class~="BBBBB"}`

Prometheus shows an error when I try to do so.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that there is no way to do it so far: [open issue on prometheus github](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/5097).

Answer (score 4):

The filtering for this particular question can be done via the inner series selector before applying `label_replace`. For example, the following query returns only series with `class=~"BBBBB"`:

```
label_replace(
  http_requests_total{handler=~"BBBBBController.*"},
  "class",
  "$1",
  "handler",
  "([a-zA-Z0-9]+)Controller.*"
)
```

P.S. While Prometheus doesn't provide the ability to post-filter time series by label values after they are selected by [series selector](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#time-series-selectors), this can be done in VictoriaMetrics - Prometheus-like system I work on. See [label_match](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#label_match) and [label_mismatch](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#label_mismatch) functions.

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed that there is a grafana tag under this question, so if you don't mind to use grafana to achive that goal, then there is another way.

By using Grafana... 7.x+ IIRC, you can use `Transform` to reprocess the raw result set.

For instance, I have a Query result like this:

[image]

Add a `Filter data by values` plugin. You can set `Match any` in it, and add a regex condition. Set field `Class` matches `BBBBB` or anything you want.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the [record rules](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/recording_rules/) feature might be helpful to you. Following is the steps for your reference

1. create record rule.
   Prometheus allow us to set 2 type rules, one is alert rule another one is record rule. Record rule will create new metrics  by the setting that you provide on Prometheus server setting. Here is the sample according your description.

```html
groups:
- name: http_requests_total_new_merics
  rules:
  - record: http_requests_total_new
    expr: label_replace(http_requests_total, "class", "", "handler", "([a-zA-Z0-9]+)Controller.*")
```

then Prometheus will create new metrics named `http_requests_total_new`

2. Using PromQL to query according your needs, e.g.

- http_requests_total_new{class!="BBBBB"}

Answer (score 0):

**solution**:

You can achieve it via joining two metrics, for example I need to group pods by nodes filtered by the name of the deployment that I pass as grafana variable

```sql
count by (node)
(
  label_replace(kube_pod_info{namespace="prod"}, "deployment", "$1", "pod", "(.*)-(.*)-(.*)$") 
  * on (deployment) group_left(job) 
       kube_deployment_labels{namespace="prod", deployment=~"prod-celery-beat-v1|prod-api-v1|prod-backend-v1"}
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems and this is my solution:

```
label_repalce({__name__=~"foo($lable)"}, 'lable', ...)
```

The label is which you will generate, you can set it on Grafana.
This method works for me.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned here already there is no easy and straightforward way of filtering this.

Some of the [simpler] filtering can be done with combination of [set operators](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#logical-set-binary-operators) `unless`, `and` and `or`.

So, if you want to leave only metrics with label `l1` equal to values `v1` or `v2` or empty value (missing label `l1`) you can use following:

```
<my_initial_query>
 and on(l1) (
   absent(_{l1="v1"}) or
   absent(_{l1="v2"}) or
   absent(_{})
 )
```

Similarly, to exclude metrics with label `l1` equal to values `v1` or `v2` or empty value (missing label `l1`):

```
<my_initial_query>
 unless on(l1) (
   absent(_{l1="v1"}) or
   absent(_{l1="v2"}) or
   absent(_{})
 )
```

Here, `absent(_{l1="v1"})` produces pseudo-metric with label `l1="v1"` (`_` is simply used as a name of non-existing metric. You can use `absent(non_existent{l1="v1"})` if it's easier).

Also, please note, that this trick is based on `absent` "tr[ying] to be smart about deriving labels" as [official documentation states](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#absent). This trick only works for label selectors using `=`. Something like `l1=~"v1|v2|"` wouldn't work.

Demo queries showing this principle in action can be found [here](https://prometheus.demo.do.prometheus.io/graph?g0.expr=go_info&g0.tab=1&g0.stacked=0&g0.show_exemplars=0&g0.range_input=1h&g1.expr=label_replace(go_info%2C%20%22short%22%2C%20%22%241%22%2C%20%22version%22%2C%20%22.*%5C%5C.(%5B%5E2%5D*)%22)%0A%23example%20of%20data%20after%20%60label_replace%60&g1.tab=1&g1.stacked=0&g1.show_exemplars=0&g1.range_input=1h&g2.expr=label_replace(go_info%2C%20%22short%22%2C%20%22%241%22%2C%20%22version%22%2C%20%22.*%5C%5C.(%5B%5E2%5D*)%22)%0A%20and%20on(short)%20(%0A%20%20absent(_%7Bshort%3D%224%22%7D)%20or%0A%20%20absent(_%7Bshort%3D%225%22%7D)%20or%0A%20%20absent(_)%0A%20)%0A%23%20Example%20of%20%22positive%22%20filtering&g2.tab=1&g2.stacked=0&g2.show_exemplars=0&g2.range_input=1h&g3.expr=label_replace(go_info%2C%20%22short%22%2C%20%22%241%22%2C%20%22version%22%2C%20%22.*%5C%5C.(%5B%5E2%5D*)%22)%0A%20unless%20on(short)%20(%0A%20%20absent(_%7Bshort%3D%224%22%7D)%20or%0A%20%20absent(_%7Bshort%3D%225%22%7D)%20or%0A%20%20absent(_)%0A%20)%0A%23%20Example%20of%20%22negative%22%20filtering&g3.tab=1&g3.stacked=0&g3.show_exemplars=0&g3.range_input=1h).